# Is it possible to use a docker image for multiple VM instances?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, python-3.7, google-container-registry

I have created a docker image and uploaded it to the Container registry. The docker image is run by `docker run --rm docker_image event-id device-name`. The output of the docker image is a pdf file that is uploaded to the Cloud Storage. I am creating a VM instance that will be using the docker with a storage trigger cloud function as follows:

**main.py**

```
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1',cache_discovery=False)
project = PROJECT_NAME 
zone = 'us-central1-a'  
instance_name = project + '-' + event-id

container_data = "spec:\n  containers:\n  - name: " + instance_name + "\n    image: gcr.io/PROJECT_NAME/docker_image \n    args:\n    - " + event-id + "\n    - " + device-name  +"\n    stdin: True\n    tty: True\n  restartPolicy: OnFailure\n# This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice. Please\n# use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine."

config = {
    "canIpForward": False,
    "confidentialInstanceConfig": {
        "enableConfidentialCompute": False
    },
    "deletionProtection": False,
    "description": "",
    "disks": [
        {
        "autoDelete": True,
        "boot": True,
        "deviceName": instance_name,
        "initializeParams": {
            "diskSizeGb": "10",
            "diskType": "",
            "labels": {},
            "sourceImage": "projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-stable-93-16623-39-6"
        },
        "mode": "READ_WRITE",
        "type": "PERSISTENT"
        }
    ],
    "displayDevice": {
        "enableDisplay": False
    },
    "guestAccelerators": [],
    "labels": {
        "container-vm": "cos-stable-93-16623-39-6"
    },
    "machineType": "projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/e2-medium",
    "metadata": {
        "items": [
        {
            "key": "gce-container-declaration",
            "value": container_data
        }
        ]
    },
    "name": instance_name,
    "networkInterfaces": [
        {
        "accessConfigs": [
            {
            "name": "External NAT",
            "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
            }
        ],
        "subnetwork": "projects/PROJECT_NAME/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default"
        }
    ],
    "reservationAffinity": {
        "consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
    },
    "scheduling": {
        "automaticRestart": True,
        "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
        "preemptible": False
    },
    "serviceAccounts": [
        {
        "email": SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
        ]
        }
    ],
    "shieldedInstanceConfig": {
        "enableIntegrityMonitoring": True,
        "enableSecureBoot": False,
        "enableVtpm": True
    },
    "tags": {
        "items": [
        "http-server",
        "https-server"
        ]
    },
    "zone": "projects/PROJECT_NAME/zones/us-central1-a"
    }

 operation = compute.instances().insert(project=PROJECT_NAME,zone=zone,body=config).execute()
 print('VM Instance created')

 wait_for_operation(compute, PROJECT_NAME, zone, operation['name'])

 print('VM Instance started')
 request = compute.instances().start(project=PROJECT_NAME, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)
 response = request.execute()
```

Required functionlity:

Since multiple files are uploaded to the storage, the cloud function is triggered and it creates multiple VM instances. Each of these VM instances uses the same docker image. Each VM instance will upload a pdf to the storage.

If there are 2-3 VM instances, only 1 VM instance will upload the pdf. I kept the other VM instances running more than 2hrs, but the pdf did not get uploaded to the storage.

I uploaded 2 files to the storage, it created 2 VM instances. The logs of the VM instances are:

1st VM instance

```
I 2021-12-24T05:31:48.481784444Z GCE Agent Started (version 20210707.00) 
W 2021-12-24T05:31:48.493633766Z Failed to run 
"google_optimize_local_ssd" script: exec: "google_optimize_local_ssd": 
executable file not found in $PATH 
W 2021-12-24T05:31:48.493919284Z Failed to run "google_set_multiqueue" 
script: exec: "google_set_multiqueue": executable file not found in 
$PATH 
I 2021-12-24T05:31:48.594836654Z Instance ID changed, running first-boot 
actions 
I 2021-12-24T05:31:49.280012028Z OSConfig Agent (version 20210607.00) 
started. 
E 2021-12-24T05:31:49.627079309Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found. 
E 2021-12-24T05:31:49.634673669Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart unscd.service: Unit unscd.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:49.755483316Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart cron.service: Unit cron.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:49.763346458Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart crond.service: Unit crond.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:49.769306899Z Error reloading service: Failed to 
reload-or-restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.
I 2021-12-24T05:31:58.176338859Z Created google sudoers file 
I 2021-12-24T05:31:58.176538485Z Creating user mishal.
```

2nd VM instance

```
I 2021-12-24T05:31:44.031627075Z GCE Agent Started (version 20210707.00) 
W 2021-12-24T05:31:44.056742854Z Failed to run 
"google_optimize_local_ssd" script: exec: "google_optimize_local_ssd": 
executable file not found in $PATH 
W 2021-12-24T05:31:44.056880958Z Failed to run "google_set_multiqueue" 
script: exec: "google_set_multiqueue": executable file not found in 
$PATH 
I 2021-12-24T05:31:44.144234903Z Instance ID changed, running first-boot 
actions 
I 2021-12-24T05:31:44.652442138Z OSConfig Agent (version 20210607.00) 
started. 
E 2021-12-24T05:31:45.416544025Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:45.428340167Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart unscd.service: Unit unscd.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:45.605303086Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart cron.service: Unit cron.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:45.615129619Z Error restarting service: Failed to 
try-restart crond.service: Unit crond.service not found.
E 2021-12-24T05:31:45.628090867Z Error reloading service: Failed to 
reload-or-restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.
I 2021-12-24T05:31:58.178399265Z Created google sudoers file
```

Am I doing the right thing? I am really confused.

Comment: 1) What does **but this does not happen** mean? What happens, what is the error, what do the logs show? 2) You state **and it creates multiple VM instances** - is that what you want or is that another problem. Edit your question to clearly define one problem. Post multiple questions if necesssary.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added some more details in the question.

Comment: I check logs of both the VM instances, I got this error  `time="2021-12-24T10:00:31.527968215Z" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: denied: Permission denied for \"latest\" from request \"/v2/project_name/docker_image_name/manifests/latest\". "`

Comment: The service account you are using has the scope [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform) which grants the `compute.instanceAdmin.v1`,  `storage.objectViewer` and `compute.networkAdmin`  predefined IAM roles. 
Can you try granting the [**Storage Legacy Bucket Writer**](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#grant) role on the registry storage bucket to control access to images in the registry.

Comment: @Srividya - Scopes do not grant permissions. IAM Roles grant permissions. Scopes request permissions within the granted roles. If a permission is not granted by a role, the scope request will not fail. Later the API call will fail with a permission issue.